# Send value from Child Component to Parent, let the parent modify and pass it back to child

Tags: angular

Please see the sample here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dybb4v

```
  sendValueToParentForModification(e) {
//Send the value to parent
this.sendValue.emit({ childComponent: this, e: e, myValue: this.myValue });
/*
The parent modifies the value and that modified value should be used here.. 
Right now, I'm having the parent component call the function in this child "useModifiedValue".
Instead, I want the flow to somehow come over here.. so that I can call the 
"useModifiedValue" function right here, with the modified value. How to do this?
*/
```

}

Basically, I want to a value to be sent to the parent component, let the parent modify it as needed and then in the child component - I want to use the modified value.

I do not want to add another "emit" in the parent component.. Is there any way I can chain the flow of the values?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Quick question to try and understand the scenario: if you want the value on the child why does it go to the parent and return back? It doesn’t seem a good practice both of them changing the value. If only the parent changes it just send the value from the parent and create an @Input() on the child.

Comment: The parent component has the option to change it if needed. That's why it has to go to the parent and then come back to child. 
Basically - 
Child ----> Emits an event to Parent with the data
Parent -->Modifies it if needed -->> Child uses the modified data.

My problem is capturing the data modified by the parent in the child. 

something like this..
childComponent.emit({data}).done { /* use the modified values*/}

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a service to act as a "middle man" between the two. Import the service in both components, and when one changes the variable in the service it is reflected in the other. No need to emit anything except once, and subscribe in both the parent and child with OnInit().

Comment: Brandon - thanks... any chance you have a sample to demo this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
// Parent component
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: '<child-component (valueChanged)="changeValue($event)" [childValue]="childValue"></childComponent>'
})
export class ParentComponent {
  childValue: 'hello world';

  changeChildValue(newValue){
    this.childValue = newValue;
  };
}

// Child component

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: '<div>{{childValue}}</div>'
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() childValue;
  @Output() valueChanged = new EventEmmiter<any>();

  changeValue(newValue) {
    valueChanged.emit(newValue);
  }
}
```

Pass the childValue from the parent component as input.

Depending on your logic, change the childValue inside the child and then call the changeValue method with the new value. The parent component will receive that event and update the value which is automatically updated on the child